# Solving the exponential inequality $(\sqrt{2}-1)^x+(\sqrt{2}+1)^x\leq 2$ without using logarithms or calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I am trying to solve the following exponential equation:

$$(\sqrt{2}-1)^x+(\sqrt{2}+1)^x\leq 2$$

Now, obviously the solution(s) must be in the interval $(-1,1)$ since $(\sqrt{2}-1)^x$ is increasing for $x$ decreasing, $(\sqrt{2}-1)^{(-1)}=\sqrt{2}+1>2$ and $(\sqrt{2}+1)^x$ is positive; by a similar argument we can conclude that the solutions cannot be bigger than $1$ (excluded).

The book I took this exercise from says the **only** solution is $x=0$ but I don't see how to prove that without using, for example, logarithms and calculus.

So, I would appreciate any hint about how to reason about this problem, thanks.

Comment: It's an inequality with "$\leq$", equation requires an equality sign "$=$"

Comment: @Sil Mistake fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have

$$\sqrt{2}-1 = \frac 1{1+\sqrt 2}$$

So, basically, you look for $a>0$ with

$$\frac 1a + a \leq 2$$

Fact is, that because of, for example, AM-GM you have

$$\frac 1a + a \geq 2$$

with equality if and only if $a=1$.

So, the only solution to your inequality is

$$a= (1+\sqrt 2)^x = 1 \Leftrightarrow x= 0$$